# Multiple object tracking on selected objects

Tags: selected

first select four or five bounding boxes manually in a video in its 1st frame and track those bounding boxes at same time (not first select one object and track that again select another object and track) may i know will work or it won't work)

when I run program first select 3 or 4 objects manually and track at same time parallelly.

Comment: anyone know about  above question